# Transaction related issue in codeIgniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, transactions

I have a table temp_users to hold input data from users before account activation.
When validation of registration is successful a random number is generated and an email is sent to the user with that number, and also input data are added to temp_users along with that random number.
When user click the activation link in their email , a new function in controller fires on and if it runs successfully all input datas of users are sent to a table perm_users and datas of temp_users get deleted.
I'm using a model model_users.

Problem 1

```
if($this->model_users->add_temp_users($email_key)){                  
     if ($this->email->send()) {
       echo "An email has been sent to you. Click the link to activate your account.";
       } else {
       $this->model_users->delete_temp_users($email_key); 
        echo 'Some error occured, try again later.';
      }


     }else{

        echo "Some error occured, try again later.";
      }
```

Here if email sending fails(i tried disconnecting internet) data in temp_users are not getting deleted, error of lockout time expired happening.

Problem 2

```
if($this->email->send()){

    if ($this->model_users->add_temp_users($email_key)) {
      echo "An email has been sent to you. Click the link to activate your account.";
     }else {
      echo 'Some error occured, try again later.';
     }

  }else{

   echo 'Some error occured, Try again later.';
  }
```

If i use this logic, if database query fails email is still being sent.

Problem 3

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->email->send();
$this->model_users->add_temp_users($email_key);
$this->db->trans_complete();

if($this->db->trans_status() == FALSE){
 echo "Some error occured, try again later.";
}else{
 echo "An email has been sent to you. Click the link to activate your account.";
}
```

Here roll back is not occuring.

How to run this logic properly?

Comment: wow still no answer? usually i get an answer almost instantly from the helpful and kind community

Comment: could you accomplish the same thing without using transactions?

Comment: problem 1 and problem 2 are without transaction. In problem 3 i'm trying to use transaction , but most probably it won't work cause $this->email->send() is not a database query, and we can't really roll it back if email is already sent.

Comment: ok i'm more clear now. so i would say that between sending an email, and updating your database table with some info -- sending the email is more prone to error. But the bigger error will be people inputting the wrong email address! so i would suggest that in whatever message you give the user -- echo back the email address like "we have sent an email to name@domain.com". that way if they made a mistake in their email address you are giving them a chance to correct it.

Comment: and if this is critical for your application, then suggest to use codeigniter logging so that you have a record of the errors https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html